# Foundation 6 Accordion Menu - Persistent State

Tags: accordion, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to get a submenu to remain open when the user navigates to a link within that submenu. In my search I found this code which checks if the current URL matches any href and if so, toggles the class (I gather). However, I'm not able to get this working with what I assume I would want to incorporate, which is the Foundation API.

What is the best way to retain the state of an Foundation 6 Accordion Menu item?

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.main-nav a').each(function(){
    var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
    if(url.match(myHref)) {
        $('.accordion').foundation('down', $('.accordion .accordion-item.is-active .accordion-content'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the sub-menu ('ul') to the function 'down', as you are with the link 'a', the 'ul' is the parent of her 'li' (parent().parent()), with this you have the 'ul' sub-menu you want to show .

```
    $('.main-nav a').each(function(){
         var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
         var pathname = window.location.pathname;
         if(pathname.match(myHref)) {
           $('.menu').foundation('down', $(this).parent().parent());
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jherel. Your code, which I edited slightly, works.